# How to 301 redirect old URL to new URL in CakePHP 2.x with slug lookup?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I need to redirect (301) urls like this:

https://website.com/products/view/id

to:

https://website.com/products/product-name-slug

I know how to make the slug version of urls work, but I do not want to disable old ones completely, instead I want them to 301-redirect to its slug version.
I don't want them both working simultaneously as it is treated as duplicated content by Google SEO.

I also do not want to write redirect for every product in routes.php like this:

```
Router::redirect( '/product/view/1001', [ 'controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'view', 'product-1001-name-slug' ] );
```

Instead I would rather have dynamic lookup function to do it for me.

How can I do it in CakePHP 2.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Create a custom route class](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#custom-route-classes) to handle this case
- Check if the slug exists in the new slug field

  - If yes great, nothing more to do
  - If no try to lookup the slug in the old slug field

    - If it exists redirect to the new slug and set HTTP status
    - If it does not exist return false

Comment: So what you are saying is that I can replace params in CakeRoute::parse($url) function from  $params['id'] to $params['slug']?

Comment: can I use custom route class in ::redirect instead of ::connect?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example implementation of @burzum's answer:

in  routes.php:

```
Router::connect(
    '/product/view/:slug',
    array( 'controller' => 'base_products', 'action' => 'view' ),
    array( 'pass' => array( 'slug' ) )
);
Router::connect(
    '/base_products/view/:id',
    [ 'controller' => 'product', 'action' => 'view', 'model' => 'BaseProduct' ],
    [ 'routeClass' => 'IdToSlugRoute' ]
);
```

in app/Routing/Route/IdToSlugRoute.php:

```
public function parse($url) {
        $params = parent::parse($url);
        if (!$params) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!$this->response) {
            $this->response = new CakeResponse();
        }

        App::import('Model', $params['model']);
        $Model = new $params['model']();
        $instance = $Model->find('first', array(
            'conditions' => array($params['model'] . '.id' => $params['id']),
            'recursive' => 0
        ));

        $slug = getSlug( $instance[$params['model']]['id'], $instance[$params['model']]['name'] );
        $redirect = ['controller' => $params['controller'], 'action' => $params['action'], $slug];

        $status = 301;
        $this->response->header(array('Location' => Router::url($redirect, true)));
        $this->response->statusCode($status);
        $this->response->send();
        $this->_stop();
    }
```

in app/Controller/BaseProductsController.php:

```
function view($slug)
    {
        $id = getIdFromSlug($slug);

        $product = $this->BaseProduct->find('first', array(
            'conditions' => array('BaseProduct.id' => $id),
            'recursive' => 2
        ));

        ...
    }
```

additionality:

```
function getIdFromSlug( $slug ) {
    $pieces = explode( "-", $slug );

    return $pieces[0];
}

function getSlug( $id, $name ) {
    return $id . '-' . Inflector::slug($name, '-');
}
```